# Explicit calculation of dual norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a fairly basic question regarding the explicit calculation of the dual norm.
Let $$V:= \{v:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  |\, v \; \text{cont.}, \, u(0) = 0  \} $$
a vector space with the supremum norm $\|v\| = sup_{x \in [0,1]} |v(x)|$.
Now let $T: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$T(v) := \int_{0}^{1} v(t) dt $$
I have to calculate the dual norm $\|T \|_{E^*} = sup_{v \in V\backslash \{0\}} \, \frac{|T(v)|}{\|v\| }  $.

I could write
$$sup_{v \in V\backslash \{0\}} \, \frac{|T(v)|}{\|v\| } = sup_{\|v \| \leq 1} |T(v)| = sup_{\|v \| \leq 1} \Big|\int_{0}^{1} v(t) dt \Big| = ...?  $$

Some hints would be appreciated! (I know from the solution section of Brezis book, that we should have $\|T \|_{E^*} = 1$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $v\in V$ with $\|v\|\leqslant1$,$$\left|\int_0^1v(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|\leqslant\int_0^1|v(t)|\,\mathrm dt\leqslant\int_0^11\,\mathrm dt=1.$$On the onther hand, if $n\in\Bbb N$ and if you define$$\begin{array}{rccc}v_n\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&t&\mapsto&\begin{cases}nt&\text{ if }t\leqslant\frac1n\\1&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}\end{array}$$ then $v_n\in V$, $\|v_n\|=1$ and $\int_0^1v_n(t)\,\mathrm dt=1-\frac2n$. So, $\|T\|\geqslant1-\frac2n$, for any $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

$\|T\|\leq 1$ is clear. Let $f_n(x)=1$ for $x \geq \frac 1  n$ and $f_n(x)=nx$ for $0 \leq x <\frac 1 n$. Show that $Tf_n \to 1$. Since  $\|T\| \geq |Tf_n|$ for all $n$ we get $\|T|| \geq 1$.